# How to append text to end of current line using Vim function?

Tags: vim

I'd like to append text to the end of a current line in Vim. I'd like to do this within the context of a function.

How can this be done? Do I need to escape/sanitise the text?

Comment: `:h A`    ... . . . .  .

Comment: @Kent, this is a start indeed. But in scripting context a few more things that need to be known aren't explained in this section of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `normal` command with the `execute` command:

```
let text_for_appending = ' # a comment'
execute "normal! A" . text_for_appending
```

The exclamation mark is included to prevent any key mappings from being expanded. See `:help :normal` for more details.

Comment: `s/:normal/&!/`. Otherwise insert mode mappings could be triggered, and the OP doesn't seem to want to observe side effects.

Comment: Merci, @LucHermitte. I've edited to incorporate your suggestion. I've also upvoted your own answer, which is quite clever.

Answer (score 2):

With `:exe` + `:normal!` you may need to sanatize the text as you feared -- it'll depend on the kind of quotes you use, and on whether you forget to bang `:normal` and you have insert mode mappings and abbreviations.

With `setline('.', getline('.') . text)`, vim won't try to interpret the `text` you append. This seems convoluted, but this is the more robust way to proceed -- it can become way more convoluted if you start to escape things with `A`.